# Probability that sum of independent uniform variables is less than 1

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

I would like to determine the probability $\mathbb{P}(X_1+\dots+X_n\leq 1)$, where $X=(X_i)_{1\leq i\leq n}$ is a family of independent uniform random variables on $[0,1]$. My first idea is to do this by induction. The first three base cases are straightforward to determine and give us $\mathbb{P}(X_1\leq 1)=1$, $\mathbb{P}(X_1+X_2\leq 1)=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\mathbb{P}(X_1+X_2+X_3\leq 1)=\frac{1}{6}$, which suggests that $\mathbb{P}(X_1+\dots+X_n\leq 1)=\frac{1}{n!}$. Supposing this is true for a certain arbitrary integer $n$, I am having difficulties establishing the result for $n+1$, i.e. $\mathbb{P}(X_1+\dots+X_n+X_{n+1}\leq 1)=\frac{1}{(n+1)!}$. I believe the starting point should be:
$$\mathbb{P}(X_1+\dots+X_n+X_{n+1}\leq 1)=\mathbb{P}(X_1+\dots+X_n\leq 1-X_{n+1}),$$
and then somehow condition on $X_{n+1}$, but I am stuck at this point of the calculation. Any ideas of references to literature or even an alternative direct proof would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution

Comment: @d.k.o. Yes I am aware of the Irwin Hall distribution, however I would still like to establish the result as per above.

Comment: Oh. Maybe geometric approach will suffice. This probability is represented by a volume of a part of a (hyper)cube (in 2 dim it's the lower triangle)

Comment: @d.k.o. I used the geometric approach for the base cases $n=2$ and $n=3$, but it is harder to prove for an arbitrary integer

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/769545/321264.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1382459/321264

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Prove by induction the more general result: If $0\le t\le 1$, then
$$
P(S_n\le t)=\frac{t^n}{n!},
$$
where $S_n$ denotes the sum $X_1+\cdots+X_n$.
The base case $n=1$ is clear. If holds for $n$, then
 calculate for $0\le t\le 1$:
$$
P(S_{n+1}\le t)=\int_0^1P(S_n+x\le t)f(x)dx\stackrel{(1)}=\int_0^t\frac{(t-x)^n}{n!}\,dx=\frac{t^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}
$$
Note that in (1) the quantity $P(S_n\le t-x)$ is zero when $x>t$.

Comment: thanks for your answer, does this still hold for $t=1$?

Comment: @user223935: it does and you then get $\mathbb{P}(S_n\le 1)=\frac{1^n}{n!}$ but the more general hypothesis is easier to prove by induction

Comment: @user223935 Sure! And even if it $t=1$ was not included in the proof, you can take the limit as $t\uparrow 1$ (since $S_n$ has a continuous CDF).

Comment: Where did the expression $P(S_{n+1} \leq t) = \int_{0}^1 P(S_n+x\leq t) f(x) dx$ come from?

Comment: This is what I start with $P(S_{n+1} \leq t) = \int_{0}^t f_{S_{n+1}}(s_{n+1}) ds$, where $S_{n+1}$ is a continuous random variable with pdf $f_{S_{n+1}}$, but I'm kind of confused how you got the next expression. Looks like the definition of conditional probability was somehow applied, but it's not jumping out at me right now.

Comment: @Iamanon I am using $P(S_{n+1}\le t)=P(S_n+X_{n+1}\le t)=\int P(S_n+X_{n+1}\le t\mid X_{n+1}=x)f(x)\,dx$. Notice now that $P(S_n+X_{n+1}\le t\mid X_{n+1}=x)=P(S_n+x \le t\mid X_{n+1}=x)=P(S_n+x\le t)$ since $S_n$ and $X_{n+1}$ are independent.

Comment: Makes sense! Also, just from a general perspective, how do you build the intuition to condition over an extra variable? Like, in this case, what pointed you in the direction of conditioning on $X_{n+1}$?

Comment: @Iamanon Since we are attempting induction, we are trying to derive a result for $S_{n+1}$ from the result for $S_n$. This will possible if we can turn $X_{n+1}$ from a random variable into something we can treat as a constant, which motivates conditioning on $X_{n+1}$.

Comment: Oh right. I think in this case, it is a little more obvious. I feel like in some other cases, perhaps not involving induction, it's not as obvious to introduce an extra condition.

Answer (score 6):

A geometric argument should suffice.   Given that $\{X_k\}_\infty$ are all iid Uniform$(0;1)$ random variables, then:

$\mathsf P(X_1+X_2\leq 1)$ is the probability that points distributed uniformly over the unit square lie in the lower left triangle; which is $1/2$ the area of the unit square.

$\mathsf P(X_1+X_2+X_3\leq 1)$ is the probability that points distributed uniformly over the unit cube lie in the $(0,0,0)$-corner pyramid; which is $1/6$ the volume of the unit cube.

$\mathsf P(X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4\leq 1)$ is the probability that points distributed uniformly over the unit tesseract lie in $(0,0,0,0)$-corner pentachron; which is $1/24$ of the hypervolume of the unit tesseract.

And so forth.

$\mathsf P(\sum\limits_{k=1}^n X_k\leq 1)$ is the probability that points distributed uniformly over a unit $n$-hypercube lie in a corner $n$-hyperpyramid; which is $1/n!$ of the $n$-hypervolume of the unit $n$-hypercube.

Comment: This is true, but it rather presupposes that you know the hypervolume of a corner hyperpyramid