# Finding distribution and mgf of $N(x) = \min \left \{ n \ge 1: X_1 + \cdots + X_n>x\right \}$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, moment-generating-functions

Let $\left \{ X_r \right \}^\infty _{r=1} $ be a sequence of independent and identically distributed uniform on $[0,1]$ random variables. Let $0<x<1$ and define $$N(x) = \min \left \{ n \ge 1: X_1 + \cdots + X_n>x\right \}$$
(a) Show that: $$\mathbb{P}(N(x)>n)=\frac{x^n}{n!}$$

Recall that the moment generating function of a random variable $Y$ on the non-negative integers $\left\{0,1,2,...\right\}$ is defined by:$$\mathbb{E}[t^Y] = \sum ^\infty _{n=0} t^n \mathbb{P}(Y=n)$$
(b) Show that: $$\mathbb{E}[t^{N(x)}]=(t-1)e^{tx}+1$$

I am quite lost as to where to start. The only intuition I have would be that for part (a), that
$$P(X_1>x)=1-x \\ P(X_1+X_2>x)=1-\frac{x}{2}\\ \vdots\\P(X_1+\cdots+X_n>x)=1-\frac{x}{n}$$and we can notice that $$\frac{x^n}{n!}=x \cdot \frac{x}{2}\cdot \cdots \cdot\frac{x}n$$ so I think that might be related but other than that I'm stuck

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/111314/321264 and its linked posts.

Comment: @StubbornAtom so would the right way of going about it be to see this: ()=min{≥1:1+⋯+>} as the expected value?

Comment: You have $P(N(x)>n)=P(X_1+\cdots+X_n\le x)$ and this probability is calculated here for example: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1683558/321264.