# Mean and variance of $N=\min\{{n\geq1|X_1+X_2+ \cdots +X_n > x}\}$

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, uniform-distribution

Let $X_r (r \geq 1)$ be an independent random variable that is uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$ and $x$ be a number between $0$ and $1$. $N$ is defined as follows:

$$N= \min\{{n \geq 1 | X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_n > x}\}$$

prove that for any $x$, $P( N > n ) = \frac {x^n}{n!}$

And calculate the mean and the variance of $N$.

I am self-studying and I found this problem in my book. I have tried various methods but have gotten nowhere so far. I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/214399/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/111314/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1683558/321264

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Choose a random number between $0$ and $1$ and record its value. Keep doing it until the sum of the numbers exceeds $1$. How many tries do we need?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111314/choose-a-random-number-between-0-and-1-and-record-its-value-keep-doing-it-u)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wow, this is a hard question! Apologies in advance if I make any careless mistakes.

Note that $P(N > k)$ is asking: "after $k$ tries, what is the probability that the *sum of* the r.v.'s $X_1, X_2, \cdots X_k$ is still less than $x$?" This way you need **more than** $k$ r.v's to go beyond $x$.  So $P(N > k) = P(X_1 + X_2 + \cdots X_k < x)$.

I'm going to cheat and knock it down to the case of small variables first. When $k=1, P(N > k) = P(X_1 < x) = x$, so the formula works. When $k=2, P(N > k) = P(X_1 + X_2 < x)$. We condition on the first variable. That is,
\begin{align}
P(X_1 + X_2 < x) &= \int_0^x P(X_2 <x -x_1 \mid X_1 = x_1) f_{X_1}(x_1) dx_1 \\
\end{align}
where $f_{X_1}(x_1)$ is the PDF of the random variable $X_1$.
However, since $f_{X_1}$ is uniformly distributed, $f_{X_1}(x_1) = 1$ for all $x_1 \in [0,1]$. Hence,
\begin{align}
P(X_1 + X_2 < x) &= \int_0^x P(X_2 <x -x_1 \mid X_1 = x_1) (1) dx_1 \\
\end{align}
By independence, $P(X_2 <x -x_1 \mid X_1 = x_1) = P(X_2 < x -x_1)$, so,
\begin{align}
P(X_1 + X_2 < x) &= \int_0^x P(X_2 <x -x_1) dx_1 \\
&= \int_0^x \int_0^{x-x_1} 1 dx_2 dx_1.
\end{align}
Now, $\int_0^{x-x_1} 1 dx_2$ gives $(x-x_1)$, and $\int_0^x (x-x_1) dx_1 = \frac{x^2}{2}$.

For $k=3$, you can verify by a similar procedure that the integral you need is,
\begin{align}
P(X_1 + X_2 + X_3 < x) = \int^x_0 \int^{x-x_1}_0 \int^{x-x_1-x_2}_0 1 dx_3 dx_2 dx_1.
\end{align}
This gets hard to evaluate real quick, but luckily for us, we have a secret weapon! Notice that $x-x_1$ does not participate in the inner two integrals (they are integrating with respect to $x_2$ and $x_3$, hence you may let $x-x_1 = u$, and get,
\begin{align}
P(X_1 + X_2 + X_3 < x) = \int^x_0 \int^{u}_0 \int^{u-x_2}_0 1 dx_3 dx_2 dx_1.
\end{align}
But by the case of $k=2$, you know the inner two integrals works out to be,
\begin{align}
\int^{u}_0 \int^{u-x_2}_0 1 dx_3 dx_2 = \frac{u^2}{2!} = \frac{(x-x_1)^2}{2!}
\end{align}
Unsurprisingly,
$$
\int^x_0 \frac{(x-x_1)^2}{2!} dx_1 = \frac{x^3}{3!}.
$$
By now you should see a pattern. For $k=4$, you will eventually end up with
$$
\int^x_0 \frac{(x-x_1)^3}{3!} dx_1,
$$
for which you want to show this integral works out to be $\frac{x^4}{4!}$. For $k=5$, you will end up with
$$
\int^x_0 \frac{(x-x_1)^4}{4!} dx_1,
$$
for which you want to show this integral works out to be $\frac{x^5}{5!}$. What you need to prove now is that in general, the following preposition,

***Proposition***: $$\int^x_0 \frac{(x-x_1)^n}{n!} dx_1 = \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}.$$

There are many ways to do this, (brute forcing binomial expansion of $(x-x_1)^n$ is perhaps the easiest), so I will not prove it here.

Once you prove this, the fact that $P(N > k) = \frac{x^k}{k!}$ should be clear.

---

Another way to compute expectation (for discrete variables only) is by using this formula:
$$
E(X) = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} P(X \geq n)
$$
(Why is this true?) Then,
\begin{align}
E(N) &= \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} P(N \geq n) \\
&= \sum_{n-1= 0}^{\infty} P(N > n-1) \\
&= \sum_{u = 0}^{\infty} P(N > u) \\
&= \sum_{u = 0}^{\infty} \frac{x^u}{u!} \\
&= e^x.
\end{align}

---

Variance is a little tricker. We know $E(N)$ already, so the $E(N)^2$ term isn't the problem. What is problematic is the $E(N^2)$ term!
\begin{align}
 E(N^2) &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(N^2 \geq n) \\
&=P(N^2 \geq 1) + P(N^2 \geq 2) + P(N^2 \geq 3) + P(N^2 \geq 4) + ...
\end{align}
Note,
\begin{align}
& P(N^2 \geq 1) = P(N > 0) \\
&  P(N^2 \geq 2) = P(N > 1) \\
& P(N^2 \geq 3) = P(N > 1) \\
& P(N^2 \geq 4) = P(N > 1)
\end{align}
So 1 contributes 1 $P(N > 0)$ term, 2 to 4 contributes 3 $P(N > 1)$ terms, and extrapolating, 5-9 contributes 5 $P(N > 2)$ terms, 9-16 gives 7 $P(N > 3)$ terms, and so on. We hence have the following sum,
\begin{align}
E(N^2) &= P(N > 0) + 3 P(N > 1) + 5P(N > 2) + 7P(N > 3) + \cdots \\
&= 1 + 3x + 5\frac{x^2}{2!} + 7\frac{x^3}{3!} + \cdots \\
&= e^x + 2x + 4\frac{x^2}{2!} + 6\frac{x^3}{3!} + 8\frac{x^4}{4!} + \cdots \\
&= e^x + 2x(1+x+\frac{x^2}{2!} + \frac{x^3}{3!} + \cdots)\\
&= e^x + 2xe^x.
\end{align}
Thus, $\text{Var}(N) = e^x + 2xe^x - e^{2x}$, which is somehow (magically) positive for $x \in [0,1]$.

Comment: Great answer.  But variance is always positive, why should that be magical?

Comment: That's true, when I was doing the question, I thought $e^x + 2xe^x - e^{2x}$ would be negative, since the $e^{2x}$ term would outweigh the other terms, but then I remembered $x \in [0,1]$. I said magically as a joke tbh, because looking at the variance formula, it almost seems coincidental that it is positive from 0 to 1.