# Distribution of the minimum number of uniform random variables that exceed a given number

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, reference-request, random-variables

Let $X_i$, $i=1,2,3,...$ be an iid sequence of uniform random variables. I‘m interested in the distribution of
$$Y_x=\inf\left\{k\geq0\,\middle|\,\sum_{i=1}^kX_i>x\right\}$$ for $x>0$.
Does it have a name? What is known about it besides its mean?

Comment: If $X_i\sim U(0,1)$, then $P(Y_x>k)=\frac{x^k}{k!}$ for any $x\in (0,1)$. Relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/111314/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1683558/321264. Check out the several linked posts in these threads.

Answer (score 1):

Not a full answer, but if this helps:

$$P(Y_x > n) =  P(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \le x)  = G(x;n)$$

where $$ G(x;n) = \frac{1}{n!} \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor x \rfloor} (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} (x-k)^n$$

is the CDF of the [Irwin–Hall distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution).