# Suppose that $U1, U2, ..., Un$ are iid $U(0,1)$ and $Sn$ is the sum of $Ui$, show that $P(Sk ≤ t) = t^k/k!$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

We are given that $U_1, U_2,..., U_n$ are iid U(0,1), $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n U_i$ and $N = min(k:S_k>1)$.  We want to show that $P(S_k \leq t) = \frac{t^k}{k!}$.

I attempted to use induction, but I arrived at something rather wrong.
Here was my attempt.
Suppose it is true for k = 1: $P(S_1 \leq t) = \frac{t^1}{1!}$

Suppose it is true for k = n:  $P(S_n \leq t) = \frac{t^n}{n!}$

Let's see what we then get for k = n + 1.

$P(S_n \leq t)P(S_n \leq t) = \frac{t^1}{1!}\frac{t^n}{n!} = \frac{t^{n+1}}{n!}$

But this is not what we want.  Where is my error and how do I fix it?

Comment: It is not clear what you intended to say in the last equation.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1683558/321264

Comment: I meant it to read: P(S_1 ≤ t) P(S_n ≤t).  The product of those probabilities given the assumption is true.