# Volume of an n-dimensional isosceles pyramid

Tags: geometry, probability-distributions, euclidean-geometry, triangles, uniform-distribution

I was looking at the following question ([link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1683558/probability-that-sum-of-independent-uniform-variables-is-less-than-1)). To summarise, the aim is to find, for standard uniform distributions $U_i$,

$$P(U_1+\ldots+U_n \leq 1)$$

for $0\leq t\leq1$. A nice proof by induction is shown in that question. However, if we consider the 2-dimensional case, we have

$$P(U_1 + U_2 \leq t) = t^2 / 2$$
which is the area of an isosceles triangle with base and height of length $t$. For the 3D case we have a pyramid. Can this geometric argument be extended to $n$-dimensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The set of all values for the $U$s is $[0, 1] \times [0, 1] \times \ldots \times [0, 1]$, an $n$-dimensional cube.

The "face" defined by
$$
U_1+\ldots+U_n = 1
$$
is a pyramid-like shape in $n$-dimensions known as an $(n-1)$-simplex, which is the thing that mathematicians generally agree is the generalization of a triangle to higher dimensions.

Let's call this specific $(n-1)$-simplex by the name $K$.

Every point in the set defined by
$$
U_1+\ldots+U_n \leq 1
$$

is actually in the "cone" on $K$ from the origin, i.e., it's pyramid-like, with the origin as the apex. (BTW, the "pyramid" in the 3D case isn't a traditional Egyptian pyramid -- it's actually a tetrahedron, but I *think* that was what you intended).

That "cone on the set $K$" is defined as the set of all linear combinations of the form
$$
(1-t)\cdot (0, \ldots, 0) + t \cdot (v_1, \ldots, v_n),
$$
where $t$ ranges from $0$ to $1$ and $(v_1, \ldots, v_n) $ is a point of $K$. If you have some nonzero point
$$
(u_1, \ldots, u_n)
$$
in the set defined by
$$
U_1+\ldots+U_n \leq 1
$$
you can let
$$
t = u_1+\ldots+u_n
$$
and
$
v_i = \frac{u_i}{t}
$,
which gives the correspondence between this cone and the set you're interested in.

If you actually draw out all this stuff in the cases $n = 2, 3$, you'll pretty quickly see how it generalizes.